# Why is my `with-redefs-fn` rebinding ignored?

Tags: clojure, clojure.test

I am attempting to replace the `stacktrace-file-and-line` (private) function in `clojure.test`, but using `with-redefs-fn` when running tests seems to have no effect. When I execute the following code the original `stacktrace-file-and-line` is called instead of my anonymous function.

```
(with-redefs-fn 
 {#'clojure.test/stacktrace-file-and-line (fn [stacktrace] {:file "foo.clj" :line 1})}
 #(clojure.test/run-tests 'repl-test.core-test))
```

Does `with-redefs-fn` not work with private function or is there something about the `clojure.test` namespace that is preventing this from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `clojure.test` is compiled with [direct linking](https://clojure.org/reference/compilation#directlinking) and thus causing that `with-redefs-fn` and `with-redefs` won't work.

Comment: Based on this "As of Clojure 1.8, the Clojure core library itself is compiled with direct linking." I think you are correct.

Comment: I've checked the Clojure code build files (e.g. ant build.xml or maven pom.xml) and they have direct-linking property set to true but I didn't analysed if they are used for the jars published in maven central.